# Как проверить, что после чисел идут точки в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ip

Есть ip-адрес, который пользователь вводит из командной строки. Например, 10.100.100.1
Как проверить, что после чисел идут точки? (Сделать это надо без регулярных выражений и подключения дополнительных модулей)

Comment: Валидация IP адреса?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3462840/7485582

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Возможное решение:**

```py
def validIP(address):
    parts = address.split(".")
    if len(parts) != 4:
        return False
    for item in parts:
        if not item.isdigit():
            return False
        if not 0 <= int(item) <= 255:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Только если там будут не цифры, вылетит exception. Я бы ещё проверил предварительно `item` на `isdigit`. А так код хороший прям.

Comment: int(item) - без ловли исключений так  делать нельзя.

Comment: @Эникейщик - Исправил.

Comment: ``if not item.isdigit():`` 

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

```
def is_valid_ip(ip_string: str) -> bool:
    parts = ip_string.split(".")
    if len(parts) != 4:
        return False

    return all(x.isdigit() and 0 <= int(x) <= 255 for x in parts)
```

Проверка работы:

```
print(is_valid_ip('1.1.1.1'))
print(is_valid_ip('1.1.'))
print(is_valid_ip('1.1.1.1.1'))
print(is_valid_ip('255.255.255.255'))
print(is_valid_ip('255.255.255.256'))
print(is_valid_ip('255.255.abc.256'))
print(is_valid_ip('1.2.3.4.a'))
# True
# False
# False
# True
# False
# False
# False
```

---

**PS.**

Такое же решение, но с использованием функции [socket.inet_aton](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.inet_aton)

```
import socket

def is_valid_ip(ip_string: str) -> bool:
    try:
        socket.inet_aton(ip_string)
        return True
    except socket.error:
        return False
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, спасибо, понял

Answer (score -1):

Ребят я тут покопался поэтому поводу и сделал свое:

```
while True:

    ip_adress = input("Введите IP: ").split(".")

    for f in ip_adress:
        if "," in f:
            print("Адрес — это четыре числа, разделённые точками.")

        try:
            if int(f) > 255:
                print(f"{f} превышает 255.")
            else:
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print(f"{f} - это не целое число")
        break
    else:
        print("IP-адрес корректен.")
```

Код не идеальный но требования задачи выполняет

Comment: Если у вас отступы как сейчас в ответе, то break срабатывает на первом же числе, проверка до конца не дойдет, ваш код фактически не рабочий. Дополнительно проверять на запятые нет особого смысла. Если проверяете на максимальное значение, то почему не проверяете минимальное?